# logs not being logged in nodejs with JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) to combine JWT authentication with Express routing and Sequelize db management. In the tutorial they use MongoDB while I use Sequelize, but the end-result should be the same.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const apiRoutes = express.Router();

apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', (req,res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {username: req.body.username}
  }).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
    }else{
      if (user.password != req.body.password) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' })
      }else{

        console.log('I am logged');

        const token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
          expiresIn: 60*60*24
        });

        console.log(`I'm not logged :(`, token);

        res.json({
          succes: true,
          message: 'Enjoy your token!',
          token
        });
      }
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    res.json(err);
  })
});
```

What's being logged is:

```
Magic happens at http://localhost:8080
Express server listening on port 8080
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `admin`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `users` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`username` = 'Kevin frafster' LIMIT 1;
I am logged
POST /api/authenticate 200 22.819 ms - 2
```

So the logs after the token are not logged, I don't understand why. The check on username and password are working correctly and return the messages, however this POST returns:

```
{}
```

in Postman... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jwt.sign()` is throwing an error, which causes your `catch` to run.

- In an error condition, you should be setting the status code to `500`.  `res.status(500).json(...)`.
- The [properties of an `Error` are non-enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/prototype).  This means that the JSON serializer doesn't see the properties like `message`, `stack`, etc.  Since there are no enumerable properties available, an `Error` serializes to `{}`.

In your catch, add `console.error(err.stack)` to see why the sign operation fails.  You could also provide a more useful error to the client.

Comment: Oh, today I learned. Also about the convention of ``res.status(500).json(...)``, I didn't realise that. Thanks for pointing out why I get ``{}`` as a return. After doing what you told me I now get an error at least ``TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`` a few lines further : ``at Model.User.findOne.then.user``

Comment: It seems like I have to find a way to remove the circular structure of it... That's probably going to be a tough one because it's the model i get back from sequelize... Bummer